# How to ensure a Step Function executes Parameterized Query properly in AWS?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-athena, aws-step-functions

I'm currently trying to execute an Athena Query during a State Machine. The query itself needs a date variable to use in several `WHERE` statements so I'm using a Lambda to generate it.

When I run `EXECUTE prepared-statement USING 'date', 'date', 'date';` directly in Athena, I get the results I expect so I know the query is formed correctly, but when I try to do it in the state machine, it gives me the following error:

```bash
SYNTAX_ERROR: line 19:37: Unexpected parameters (integer) for function date. Expected: date(varchar(x)) , date(timestamp) , date(timestamp with time zone)
```

So my best guess is that I'm somehow not passing the execution parameters correctly.

The Lambda that calculates the date returns it in a string with the format `%Y-%m-%d`, and in the State Machine I make sure to pass it to the output of every State that needs it. Then I get a named query to create a prepare statement from within the state machine. I then use that prepared statement to run an `EXECUTE` query that requires the date multiple times, so I use an intrinsic function to turn it into an array:

```json
{
    "StartAt": "calculate_date",
    "States": {
        "calculate_date": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
            "Parameters": {
                "Payload.$": "$",
                "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:::function:calculate_date:$LATEST"
            },
            "Retry": [
                {
                "ErrorEquals": [
                    "Lambda.ServiceException",
                    "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
                    "Lambda.SdkClientException",
                    "Lambda.TooManyRequestsException"
                ],
                "IntervalSeconds": 2,
                "MaxAttempts": 6,
                "BackoffRate": 2
                }
            ],
            "Next": "get_query",
            "ResultSelector": {
                "ExecDate.$": "$.Payload.body.exec_date"
            }
        },
        "get_query": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Next": "prepare_query",
            "Parameters": {
                "NamedQueryId": "abc123"
            },
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:athena:getNamedQuery",
            "ResultPath": "$.Payload"
        },
        "prepare_query": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Next": "execute_query",
            "Parameters": {
                "QueryStatement.$": "$.Payload.NamedQuery.QueryString",
                "StatementName": "PreparedStatementName",
                "WorkGroup": "athena-workgroup"
            },
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:athena:createPreparedStatement",
            "ResultPath": "$.Payload"
        },
        "execute_query": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::athena:startQueryExecution",
            "Parameters": {
                "ExecutionParameters.$": "States.Array($.ExecDate, $.ExecDate, $.ExecDate)",
                "QueryExecutionContext": {
                    "Catalog": "catalog_name",
                    "Database": "database_name"
                },
                "QueryString": "EXECUTE PreparedStatementName",
                "WorkGroup": "athena-workgroup",
                "ResultConfiguration": {
                    "OutputLocation": "s3://bucket"
                }
            },
            "End": true
        }
    }
}
```

The execution of the State Machine returns successfully, but the query doesn't export the results to the bucket, and when I click on the "Athena query execution" link in the list of events, it takes me to the Athena editor page where I see the error listed above

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxxOm.png

Am I generating the `ExecutionParameters` wrong? Does the `createPreparedStatement` resource need a different syntax for the query parameters? I'm truly at a lost here, so any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved my problem. And I'm posting this answer in case anyone comes across the same issue.

Apparently, the `ExecutionParameters` paremeter in an Athena `StartQueryExecution` state does not respect the variable type of a JSONPath variable, so you need to manually add the single quotes when forming your array. I solved this by adding a secondary output from the lambda, with the date wrapped in single quotes so that when I make the array using instrinsic functions and pass it to the query execution, it forms the query string correctly.

Transform the output from the lambda like this:

```json
"ExecDateQuery.$": "States.Format('\\'{}\\'', $.Payload.body.exec_date)"
```

And use `ExecDateQuery` in the array intrinsic function, instead of `ExecDate`.

The final State Machine would look like this:

```json
{
    "StartAt": "calculate_date",
    "States": {
        "calculate_date": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
            "Parameters": {
                "Payload.$": "$",
                "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:::function:calculate_date:$LATEST"
            },
            "Retry": [
                {
                "ErrorEquals": [
                    "Lambda.ServiceException",
                    "Lambda.AWSLambdaException",
                    "Lambda.SdkClientException",
                    "Lambda.TooManyRequestsException"
                ],
                "IntervalSeconds": 2,
                "MaxAttempts": 6,
                "BackoffRate": 2
                }
            ],
            "Next": "get_query",
            "ResultSelector": {
                "ExecDate.$": "$.Payload.body.exec_date",
                "ExecDateQuery.$": "States.Format('\\'{}\\'', $.Payload.body.exec_date)"
            }
        },
        "get_query": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Next": "prepare_query",
            "Parameters": {
                "NamedQueryId": "abc123"
            },
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:athena:getNamedQuery",
            "ResultPath": "$.Payload"
        },
        "prepare_query": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Next": "execute_query",
            "Parameters": {
                "QueryStatement.$": "$.Payload.NamedQuery.QueryString",
                "StatementName": "PreparedStatementName",
                "WorkGroup": "athena-workgroup"
            },
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:athena:createPreparedStatement",
            "ResultPath": "$.Payload"
        },
        "execute_query": {
            "Type": "Task",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::athena:startQueryExecution",
            "Parameters": {
                "ExecutionParameters.$": "States.Array($.ExecDateQuery, $.ExecDateQuery, $.ExecDateQuery)",
                "QueryExecutionContext": {
                    "Catalog": "catalog_name",
                    "Database": "database_name"
                },
                "QueryString": "EXECUTE PreparedStatementName",
                "WorkGroup": "athena-workgroup",
                "ResultConfiguration": {
                    "OutputLocation": "s3://bucket"
                }
            },
            "End": true
        }
    }
}
```